# Creating managed object for Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Here is my entity:

[image]

Here is my class I have created:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Restaurant:NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name:String!
    @NSManaged var type:String!
    @NSManaged var location:String!
    @NSManaged var image:NSData!
    @NSManaged var isVisited:NSNumber!
}
```

I have an error:

> Invalid redeclaration of restaurant

I am new in iOS development, but I think it is related iOS version I have using (10.0).

How can I fix my code?

Comment: can help [you](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/07/17/implement-nsmanagedobject-subclass-in-swift)

Comment: check is there any other class named `Restaurant` already present?